# Predictive Ordering Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem and was wondering if anyone could help or if it is even possible to have an algorithm for something like this.

I need to create a predictive ordering wizard. So based on previous sales, we will determine that that a certain amount of an item is required. E.g 31 apples. Now i need to work out the number of cases that needs to be ordered. If the cases come in say 60, 30, 15, 10 apples, the order should be a case of 30 and a case of 10 apples.

The number of items that need to be ordered change in each row of the result set. The case sizes could also change for each item. So some items may have an option of 5 different cases and some items may land up with an option of only one case.

Other examples would be i need 39 cans of coke and the cases come in only 24 per case. Therefore needing 2 cases. I need 2 shots of baileys and the bottle of baileys come in 50cl or 70cl. Therefore i need the 50cl.

The results sets columns are ItemName, ItemSize, QuantityRequired, PackSize and PackSizeMultiple.

The ItemName is the item to be ordered. ItemSize is the size the item is used in eg. can of coke. QuantityRequired how man of the item, in this case cans of coke, need to be ordered. PackSize is the size of the case. PackSizeMultiple is the number to multiply the item with to work out how many of the items are in the case.

ps. this will be a query in SQL Server 2008

Comment: While it is probably POSSIBLE to do this in SQL, it really is something that should be handled inside an application.

Comment: Accessing memory... bin packing... NP complete... procedural code rather than SQL... no, I can;t quite do it.

Comment: There's not an efficient way to do this with set based logic...you will need to use a cursor and a bunch of temp variables that keep getting redefined, which is better done inside you calling application.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a UOM (Unit of Measure) table and a function to calc co-pack measure count and and unit count measure qty. with UOM type based on time between orders. You would also need to create a cron cycle and freeze table managed by week/time interval in order to create a freeze view of the current qty sold each week and the number of units since last order. Based on the 2 previous orders to your prior order you would set the current prediction based on min time between the last 2 freeze cycles containing an order and the duration of days between them. based on the average time between orders and the unit qty in each order, you can create a unit decay ratio percentage based on days and store it in each slice forward. Based on a reference to this data you will be able to create a prediction that will allow you to trigger a notice to sales or a message to the client to reorder. In addition, if you engage response data from sales based on unit count feedback from the client, you can reference an actual and tune your decay rate against your prediction. You should also consider managing and rolling up these freezes by month, so that you can view historical trending and forecast revenue based on velocity of reorder and same period last year. Basically this is similar to sales forcasting and we are switching out your opportunity percentage of close with Predicted Remaining Qty. percentage remaining.